# Simulating amazon.com best seller for books

Tags: algorithm

I was just going through amazon.com and an interesting thing that caught my eye is how they calculate **best sells in books**.

I was thinking of writing a sample program to calculate this. I was thinking that suppose i am calculating best sellers for the month than just sum the sales count of the individual books and show the top 10. Is it ok or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

One more interesting thing can happen: suppose one book having `id1` was sold 10 pieces on first day but after that it has not been sold but book having `id2` is getting sold for 1 or 2 pieces regularly. So how it would affect the best seller calculation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds about right. Depends on how exactly you want to define it.

"best sellers" is the number of units sold.

Another way to do it, if you don't want to fix it to one month is to have some distribution function (like square decay, t^2) and add the counts weighted by the distribution function.
This way, even though you don't have a fixed timed window you look at both new comers and old books. Your function should look like this:

```
for a_book in books:
    score = 0
    for a_sale in sales[a_book]:
        score += 1 / (days(now() - a_sale.time()) ** 2)  # pow 2
```

I think you get the idea. You can try different functions like exp(days) or different powers. Experiment and see what makes sense for you.

Comment: Interesting, can you please elaborate on this? And please see my latest edit in the question, i think you are going in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: what is this `** 2  # pow 2`?

Comment: @Trying in python `** 2` is power 2. The rest is just comment.

Comment: how it will decay a score of a book if it was sold before 15 days but it is not getting sold since than.

Comment: @Trying you recompute the score. Because the `now()` changes it will get lower score.

Comment: suppose two books are there i.e. `book1`, `book2` . `book1` was sold before 5 days and `book2` was sold just one day before. So ideally the `book2` should get the higher score than `book1` but here `now - a_sale.time()` will give a higher score to `book1` instead. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Trying Sorry, my bad. You should use the inverse of that thing. I'll fix my answer.